# Reset cumprod in function

Tags: r, zoo, rolling-computation

I am trying to create a function to calculate a rolling `cumprod`. The function must allow for a sliding window. I got the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
library(zoo)
test1 <- data.table(time=as.yearmon(2000 + seq(0, 35)/12),a=rep(1:12,3),outcome1=rep(cumprod(1:12),3))
test2 <- data.table(time=as.yearmon(2000 + seq(0, 35)/12),a=rep(rnorm(36)))
test2[,outcome2:=c(NA,NA,cumprod(test2$a[3:8]),rep(NA,6),cumprod(test2$a[15:20]),rep(NA,6),cumprod(test2$a[27:32]),rep(NA,4))]
```

test1 simply calculates a cumprod over 12 months, then again, etc., to illustrate the idea without a sliding window. test2 shows the intended calculation: A cumprod from exemplary March to August, then an empty window of 6 months, before the next calculation starts in March of next year.

A while ago I tried to create a solution that manually calculated start and end points for a rather big dataset, but the function inside a loop was too slow/not feasible. I believe with `zoo` this could be faster. I was testing the following:

```
rollapply(c(1:12,1:12), width = 12, prod, partial = TRUE, align = "right")
```

..but so far, could not get it to reset properly after 12 months. Also, adding a window with `by` inside rollapply was not possible. Any hints are appreciated!

Please note that my full dataset does not always start in January, so indexing is not that easy. I wanted to avoid a panel here to keep it simple.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks a lot, that solves the first case, but I currently don't see a way on how to implement a sliding window (as in test2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ym` is a yearmon vector then `as.integer(ym)` is the year and `cycle(ym)` is the month number so:

```
test1[, out := cumprod(a), by = as.integer(time)] 

test2[, out := cumprod(ifelse(cycle(time) %in% 3:8, a, NA)), 
  by = .(as.integer(time), cycle(time) %in% 3:8)]
```